# Is there any regular pattern to figure out where to put ... in templates?

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

I got confused with the location where the `...` should be put when using template parameter packs.

For example, in template parameter list, we should use `typename ...Ts`, while in a parameter list, it becomes `Ts...ts`.

When instantiate a template, it becomes `tuple<Ts...>` and most confused me is `std::forward<Args>(args)...`, the `...` is out side the parentheses. Until then, I force myself to just remember this, until today I see this: `sizeof...(Params)`, I think I must understand the regular pattern to avoid further confused.

So could anybody help how to treat the `...` to fully understand the location where to put it?

Comment: is [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) helps?

Comment: @yaodav I think the site doesn't explain why `...` placed on where in each case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows the thing being repeated. A name that follows is like multiple names.

In `template<typename... Ts>` we are declaring multiple `typename`s, e.g. `template<typename Ts0, typename Ts1, typename Ts2>`.

In `void foo(Ts... ts)`, we are declaring multiple parameters, using the multiple types, e.g. `void foo(Ts0 ts0, Ts1 ts1, Ts2 ts2)`

In `std::tuple<Ts...>` we are using the multiple types to instantiate `std::tuple`, e.g. `std::tuple<Ts0, Ts1, Ts2>`

In `std::forward<Args>(args)...` we are using multiple expressions, e.g. `std::forward<Args0>(args0), std::forward<Args1>(args1), std::forward<Args2>(args2)`

`sizeof...` is a named operator, distinct from `sizeof`